# Getting "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" after first http request to Dreamfactory

Tags: angularjs, typescript, dreamfactory

I'm trying to make an http request to a Dreamfactory backend.

```
return this.$http({
   method: "GET",
   url: "http://.../DMO_emails?filter=nom%20LIKE%20%27xxx%25%27%20OR%20nom%20LIKE%20%27%25%20xxx%25%27",
   headers: {
      "X-Dreamfactory_Application-Name": "appName"
});
```

After the first request, any request returns an error:

> net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
return this.$http({
    method: "GET",
    url: http://.../DMO_emails?filter=nom%20LIKE%20%27xxx%25%27%20OR%20nom%20LIKE%20%27%25%20xxx%25%27,
    headers: {
        "X-Dreamfactory_Application-Name": "appName"
});
```

to this

```
return $http({
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://.../DMO_emails?filter=nom%20LIKE%20%27xxx%25%27%20OR%20nom%20LIKE%20%27%25%20xxx%25%27",
    headers: {
        "X-Dreamfactory_Application-Name": "appName"
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Unfortunately, it doesn't solve my problem. I use arrow functions in typescript and this is why I use the `this.`